# How to set username and password on htdocs directory on apache xampp on windows on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, apache

I try to set username and password on one folder in htdocs.

1. I create a .htaccess file with this lines:

   ```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Resticted Area"
   AuthUserFile "c:/xampp/htdocs/meteo/.htpasswd"
   require valid-user
   ```
2. Second I create file .htpasswd in the same directory: c:/xampp/htdocs/meteo/
   with this line:

   ```
   meteo:$apr1$xdk8nytj$Cyq2hTCYSAEpRqa6tknyb1
   ```

When I save the files and restart the apache I can't see the username and password authentication. Just didn't work.

What can I do more to lock this folder?